# Pygame-GUI module: How to create a transparent UILabel

Tags: pygame, uilabel, transparency

Id like to create a transparent background for pygame_gui.elements.UILabel so the content can be displayed over an image without a coloured background.
Im using a json theme which is best practice for pygame_gui, the key word being "dark_bg" to enter a hexadecimal value. Ive tried "None" and " " both dont produce the desired results and there doesnt appear to be another key word that allows for transparency.
Any ideas?

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pygame_gui, if you want a fully transparent thing, you enter the color as "#00000000"

Each two digits represent R, G, B, and A (alpha, transparency) successively.

Comment: Thanks mate, I didnt know that about hex colours, now it makes sense.